# aplay does not play audio when run by systemd

Tags: linux, qt, shell, systemd, qprocess

I'm developing a Qt application which includes the following block of code to play sound

```
QString soundApp = "/usr/bin/aplay";
QStringList soundFile;
soundFile << "/home/pi/urna-files/sources/som-longo.wav";

QProcess *playSound = new QProcess;
playSound->start(soundApp, soundFile);
```

The sound plays fine when the app is run from command line.

When I use systemd and unit file to start the application after boot, QProcess does not play the audio.

```
[Unit]
Description=Voting Machine Launch Service

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/pi/urna
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What should I do to have it working? Is there something more to add in the unit file? or any other argument for QProcess?

Comment: When you say it plays the sound when run from commandline, did you switch to the user that the process will run as when being started through systemd?
I.e. if you launched it with your normal user account, then it might behave differently then when it is run as a non-logged-in use

Comment: I think this question may well be ''`aplay `gives no output when run by systemd" - I would check that you can run `aplay` successfully from systemd before pointing the finger at `QProcess`.

Comment: Btw, such a simple app wouldn't need Qt. You can write a simple bash script for it.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Adding "User=pi" under [Service] worked. The sound plays fine now. @KevinKrammer would you like to write the answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto it's just a block of code of another application. I'm developing a voting machine for schools so kids can experience voting. The machine playing sounds is just a part of it.

Comment: @GiovanniBauermeister Why don't you use `QMediaPlayer` to play the music?

Comment: @GiovanniBauermeister: done, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process probably needs to be run as the user "pi".

That can be done in the `Service` section

```
[Service]
User=pi
```